# SublimeText2 Custom Scope

Tags: sublimetext2

I have a number of different types of projects that use similar code, and my goal is to make snippets and key bindings in SublimeText2 that only activate on a given project.

So, for instance, I have `jsg1.html` through `jsg40.html`, and I also have `kwa1.html` through `kwa40.html`. Each of these two groups has code unique to them, and I want to create different snippets and key bindings for each.

This has led me to want to create custom file-types, like `.kwa` and `.jsg`, so that I can create the snippets/key-bindings with a scope set to be those file types.

However, I can't make it work. This is what I've tried:

a.sublime-snippet

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<a href="$1" style="font-family: Segoe UI, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial;  color:#2f6497; font-size:14px; text-decoration:underline;">$2</a>
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>aj</tabTrigger>
<scope>source.jsg</scope>
</snippet>
```

jsg.tmLanguage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>fileTypes</key>
  <array>
    <string>jsg</string>
  </array>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>jsg</string>
  <key>scopeName</key>
  <string>source.jsg</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Both of these files are in my `Packages/User` folder. However, I have a file, `test.jsg`, and the snippet won't activate in it.

So the questions are:

What's the best way to create custom scopes for groups of HTML files which will use the same key bindings and snippets? Is it creating a custom scope by creating a custom syntax for a new filetype? Or is there a better way? If this is the best way, why doesn't my snippet work in my `.jsg` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out. To generate your own key-bindings and snippets, you'll need to create a custom `scope`. To display the current scope of your document, you can use the hotkey:

`Ctrl + ⇧ + Alt + P`

If you open an `html` file and run this command, you should see that it displays `text.html`. The goal is to make a filetype that highlights like `html` syntax, yet displays the `scope` of `text.we` where `.we` is our custom filetype (which is to say, it can be anything we want). We can then use that `scope` in our key-bindings and snippets files.

First things first: we need to make sure our custom filetype isn't already associated with `html`. This happens if you set the setting under `View - Syntax - Open all with current extension as...`, which you might initially do in an effort to make your filetype have the same highlighting as `html`. Don't worry, we'll still do that, but we have to go about it another way.

If you've already done it, locate the `JSON` file `../Path/to/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Users/HTML.sublime-settings` and delete the extension you associated from the attribute `extensions`. If you're having trouble finding the `Packages` folder on Windows, it's typically hidden away in `User/AppData/Roaming`.

So now that we've disassociated our files, we must first find the settings file of the language that uses the highlighting we want. In my case, it was `html`, so I went to `../Path/to/Sublime Text 2/Packages/HTML`. Copy the files `html.tmLanguage` and `Comments.tmPreferences` and put them anywhere in `Packages`. For organization, I put them in `Packages/Users/xxx` where `xxx` is my custom filetype. When we make snippets later, I'll also suggest you keep them there so that everything related to your filetype is in one place.

Anyway, rename the files accordingly, based on your filetype. Within the file, you'll need to change three attributes: `fileTypes` (it's at the beginning), `name`, and `scope` (those last two are at the very end). Replace the content of those accordingly. Be sure the `scopeName` takes the form `text.___`.

Change up the `scope` of the `Comments.tmPreferences` file and you'll be good to go with your custom filetype. It'll now display the highlighting of `html` files and allow you to use it as a `scope` in snippets and key-bindings.

Also, if your custom files are `HTML` files, browsers won't have any problem displaying them when you open them up.

Mission accomplished!